# Powershell chat server working in background

Tags: powershell

It is possible for [poshchat server](https://learn-powershell.net/2012/03/05/poshchat-1-of-2-building-a-chat-server-using-powershell/) to work in the background?

When I close the PowerShell console, I see the service running in task manager but I can't have the client connect to this server anymore.

Comment: Why don't you ask the author Boe Prox?

Comment: He did not answer my other question, probably busy. However I'm interested in whether this is possible in powershell. Not necessarily in chat server but general.